# CordovaPromiseFS is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, browserify

I can't get [cordova-promise-fs](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-promise-fs) to work in my cordova application.

What I have: index.html which includes one js file created by browserify. This js file contains content of cordovapromisefs.js, promiscuous.js and my own code, which is:

```
require('../node_modules/cordova-promise-fs/dist/CordovaPromiseFS.js');

var fs = CordovaPromiseFS({
            persistent: true, // or false
            storageSize: 20 * 1024 * 1024, // storage size in bytes, default 20MB 
            concurrency: 3, // how many concurrent uploads/downloads?
            Promise: require('../node_modules/promiscuous/promiscuous.js') // Your favorite Promise/A+ library! 
        });

(function () {
    "use strict";


    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(fs);
    };  
} )();
```

I thought this should get the job done, but this leads me to "Uncaught ReferenceError: CordovaPromiseFS is not defined"

Would love to be pointed into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Browserify to build your bundle, so instead of requiring the already-bundled `cordova-promise-fs/dist/CordovaPromiseFS.js` file, require the module itself, like this:

```
var CordovaPromiseFS = require('cordova-promise-fs');
```

That will include the `cordova-promise-fs/index.js` file in your bundle which - unlike the already-bundled file - is a CommonJS module that exports the factory function.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Apparently I didn't fully grasp what browserify was doing already and what require did.

Answer (score 0):

try and assign the value that returns from `require`:

```js
var CordovaPromiseFS = require('../node_modules/cordova-promise-fs/dist/CordovaPromiseFS.js');
```

you can also build CordovaPromiseFS as a browser library yourself, with webpack. [the repo's readme](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-promise-fs#contribute) suggests that you clone the source and run the available `prepublish` command:

```sh
npm install webpack -g
npm run-script prepublish
```

this command basically packs CordovaPromiseFS's index.js file and the packed dist file and exposes it to a variable ([see the source](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-promise-fs/blob/master/package.json#L7)).